# ¿Como usar acentos al escribir los dos apellidos como una sola palabra?

Tags: ortografía

Estoy mandando tarjetas postales a votantes en los EU de una lista oficial. Algunas personas han optado por escribir sus dos apellidos como una sola palabra. ¿En tal caso - como por ejemplo Vasquezmartinez o Ramirezcastillo - dónde deben caer los acentos?

Comment: Janette: Here is what I would do: Put the first last name as a middle name and the second under last name. Forget accent marks. In any case, they would not apply. I have never seen accent marks in US election documents. If you do what I suggesst , a printer will print out the name correctly.

Comment: Furthermore, they wrote them that way because there was no enough room in the last name box to leave a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Palabras compuestas sin guión

> Cuando nos encontramos ante una palabra compuesta de dos o más lexemas, que se escriben sin guión, solo lleva tilde, si lo necesita según las reglas generales de acentuación, el último componente. A saber:
> • décimo + séptimo: decimoséptimo
> • tío + vivo: tiovivo
> • porta + lámparas: portalámparas

<sub>*[Centro Virtual Cervantes](https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/alhabla/MUSEO_hORRORES/museo_021.htm)*</sub>

Comment: No funciona para nombres mal escritos. Nadie en el mundo hispanófono añade tildes a los nombres que no deben estar juntos. Y aqui habra que separar los nombres. Sé que no debes estar al corriente pero no queria que la pregunta se contestará como si fuera un cosa normal.

Comment: Puessss.... Hablando de tildes, has omitido unas cuantas ‍♂️

Comment: Sí, Danielillo El español es mi *cuarto idioma*. Y confundo tildes con el portugués. Pero no cabe duda que no tiene ningún sentido añadir tildes a nombres escritos incorrectamente. Mi errores con tildes no tienen nada que ver con lo que digo. En todo caso, estoy segura de que la estructura de estas frases están bien.

Comment: [mis errores], no mi.